# How to design a calenderview with events?

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-calendar

[image]

For the past week I've searched across the internet, for finding a possible ui or library that could help in designing a calender view with events (similar to the image), but still I've not come across a valid solution. If someone could suggest me a solution or a library that may help in designing calenderview almost as shown in image, it would be really helpful

PS: I'm not posting the code for this question as I've not really found a possible solution that could be modified further so as to get the solution but this does not mean that I have not tried already.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View (or any) it used to draw months on view pager and days on grid view. This can be one approach you can use. You can customize this library or create your own to fulfill your requirement. This question is broad and no straight full answer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar necessity a few months ago for a project I was working on. The most useful guidance I've found was to just create my own custom calendar (using `LinearLayout` and `GridView/ArrayAdapter`) and make it do and have what I need.

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/meetu-engineering/create-your-custom-calendar-view-10ff41f39bfe) really put me on the right path.

But I also exported the calendar module out of my project into a public library, [android-tiled-calendar](https://github.com/kndombe/android-tiled-calendar). So feel free to check it out if you just want something already done and ready to use. It's mainly a month calendar view that lets you add tiles to each month cell with a custom text and custom color. The instructions to include the library as a dependency in your project are provided there.

I'll hopefully push some changes soon to make it possible to change the overall theme color (like for enabling dark mode).

But anyways. I thought I'd share this because I wished I found someone that had shared a similar calendar implementation when I myself was looking for one.

---

**Update**

The support for setting dark mode, light mode and custom colors has been added, along with some screenshots.